# Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, formatting, conditional

I have a custom list which contains a field called `Status`. In the `AllItems` view, I would like to color code each line item based on the value of `Status`. Is this possible to do withing SharePoint Designer or SharePoint itself?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called `Client Rendering Mode (CSR)` which represents a rendering engine for list views, list forms and search results. I would recommend you to consider the following approach for your task.

### How to highlight the rows using CSR

Below example demonstrates how to highlight list task rows based on their status

Template code:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  {
          'Not Started' : '#FFF1AD',  
          'In Progress' : '#FFD800',
          'Completed' : '#01DF3A' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Status"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 

});
```

### How to apply the changes

There are at least two options how to apply the changes:

1. Via [JSLink property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.jslink.aspx) of web part
2. Place JavaScript template on page via `Script Editor`/`Content Editor`
   web parts

Here is how to apply the changes using the **second option**:

1. Switch the page into edit mode
2. Add `Script Editor` webpart right below the list view web part.
3. Put the specified code by wrapping it using `script` tag code into the Script Editor, for example: `<script type="text/javascript">{Template JS code goes here}</script>`
4. Save the page

### Results

[image]

To get acquainted with CSR I would recommend the following articles:

- [INTRODUCTION TO CLIENT-SIDE RENDERING IN SHAREPOINT 2013](http://www.rbradbrook.co.uk/blog/2013/04/14/introduction-to-client-side-rendering-in-sharepoint-2013/)
- [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

Comment: Not the OP, but I've tried this and it isn't working for me. In normal view it doesn't color the lines, but if I edit the page the coding shows up. Is there something that prevents a script editor part script from working outside of edit mode?

Comment: Hmm.. the only reason I can think of now is MDS.. Please follow this for a details http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx

Comment: MDS isn't enabled for this site. I'm getting a message in the console "The XSS Auditor refused to execute a script in '...Forms/AllItem…ew=Shared&InitialTabId=Ribbon.WebPartPage&VisibilityContext=WSSWebPartPage' because its source code was found within the request. The auditor was enabled as the server sent neither an 'X-XSS-Protection' nor 'Content-Security-Policy' header."

Comment: Well now it seems to be working in both ie9 (don't ask!) and chrome. But for awhile it would work in one or the other. And if I enter Edit mode and come back it seems to be broken for awhile

Comment: Although I had to create a new page and include the custom list on it instead of having this apply to the `AllItems.aspx` page, this did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: This is working fine for me unless you filter any column and edit an item. After editing and closing the item, I get the error: 'TypeError: Unable to get the value of the property "style": object is null or undefined'?!

Comment: how about the color of a specific column?

Comment: This works perfectly! @VadimGremyachev One question though, the first column I am using in my list is title, and I do not want that one cell to be colored but everything else, yes. How can I apply td:not(:first-child) to this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible through new feature of SP2013 called JSLink.

With JS Link, users can add a reference to their JavaScript Files as a WebPart property, and Control the Rendering of Fields & Items in Views, List Forms (Display,New,Edit) and event in WebParts.Before you use the js file, it is recommended that the JavaScript file should be Uploaded as a new JavaScript Display Template in Site’s Master Page Gallery.JavaScript Display Template Content Type has some special Site Columns added to it that will help specify the target element (view,form,webpart etc..) where the JavaScript File’s Custom Rendering will be Implemented.

Here is the Before and After looks like –
[image]

Initial List –
Create Custom List before

[image]

Resulting items

For step by step process on how to achieve this, refer to [this](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/04/04/color-code-list-items-with-javascript-using-js-link-in-sharepoint-2013/) link.

Where instead of `ctx.CurrentItem.Sales`, you can refer to your `status` field internal name in list.

Answer (score 2):

## Microsoft disabled all this in versions 2016 and later, it still works in older SP version and non-Modern Experiences

### See: [June 13th 2017 Microsoft blocked handling HTML markup in SharePoint calculated fields - how to get the same functionality back](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218102/june-13th-2017-microsoft-blocked-handling-html-markup-in-sharepoint-calculated-f)

---

**Original answer:**

If you don't mind:

- Always obeying the Microsoft SharePoint 2013 way of doing things
- writing a separate JavaScript file
- Uploading it somewhere in SharePoint
- Creating a JSlink connection everywhere you want to execute it
- or messing around with extra webparts

**then CSR is the best option**

If you:

- Are not afraid to use something that has worked since 2010 (and works in SP2010)
- do not want to create separate files for display logic
- want a solution that works no matter where a View Column is displayed
- want a solution that can be wrapped in a List Template
- works even if there are multiple Views of the same List on One page

**Then you could add the JavaScript logic to a Calculated Column.**

Set the datatype to Number and it will evaluate your HTML/JavaScript

Create a Calculated Column "ColorStatus"
Paste the Formula:

```
=[Status]
"<img src=""/_layouts/images/blank.gif""  "
&" onload=""{"
&"  this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.backgroundColor="
&"  ({"
&"    'Not Started':'#FFF1AD',"
&"    'Draft':'pink',"
&"    'Reviewed':'lightgreen',"
&"    'Scheduled':'lightcoral',"
&"    'Published':'none',"
&"    'Final':'limegreen',"
&"    'Expired':'indianred'"
&"    })['"&[Status]&"']"
&" }"">"
```

And set the Datatype to number.
Add to Default View
Do **not** add to Content Types (or the Formula will show up as text on Forms) this works in Views only!!

Detail descscription on How it works at: http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How

Of course there are drawbacks;
biggest one is that the HTML/Javascript contents shows up as text in Alert messages

The fun part is you can use all you SharePoint Formula skills on the *&[Status]&* part to get any result you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve with Java Script. Anoter example in the blog of **Laura Rogers @WonderLaura**.

Link: [SharePoint Conditional Formatting](https://wonderlaura.com/2014/09/11/sharepoint-conditional-formatting/)

Image:

[image]

Hope it will helpfully!

Comment: Please note the above link is broken and here is the new link for the same

"https://wonderlaura.com/2014/9/11/sharepoint-conditional-formatting/"