# Calculate age (YYMMDD) date

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript

I've managed to calculate age using only "Year", but I would like to know how you can do this using a complete date ( YYMMDD ),

This is the code I used to calculate age using only year:

```
function Onclick() {
var Text1 = $("#Text1").val();
var datetoday = new Date();
var today = datetoday.getFullYear();
var datebirthday = new Date();
datebirthday.setFullYear(Text1);
var birthday = datebirthday.getFullYear();
var age = today - birthday;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should work for you.  First it does a Year compare, then reduces a year if the months or days do not align.

**Edit**:  The expected Date format is 'YYYY/MM/DD'

```
function Onclick() { 
        var today = new Date();
        var birthDate = new Date($("#Text1").val());
        var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
        var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
        if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
            age--;
        }
}
```

The correct age is stored in the age variable.
Heres a good thread about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript

Comment: Using your code, which format do i enter the date in? YYYY/MM/DD?

Comment: I updated the answer for you, but YYYY/MM/DD is correct. But you can use anything that Date() accepts. See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Thank you! it works perfectly, and thank you for the link.

Answer (score 1):

[setFullYear](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setfullyear.asp) takes 3 parameters for Year, Month , Day
Be aware in Javascript Months start at 0 for january, so 11 is december!!

```
Date.setFullYear(year,month,day)
```

If there is no issue to add extra libraries, then add [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/), this helps a lot in working with dates.

In 
[Can anyone color code a column with an if statement?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145693/can-anyone-color-code-a-column-with-an-if-statement/145702#145702) the javascript Today calculation is done **inside** a Calculated Column Formula (can only be used in Views, does not work on Forms) and colors the View Items based on a Date range.