# Calculate 70 plus formula

Tags: date-time

I am trying calculate a UAT 70 day view that adds 70 days to today's date which represented below by the "`CalcToday`" column minus the `UAT START DATE` field plus 70 days (mm-dd-yyyy).  The formula below returns dates with value that equal ,02-09-1900 and 02-11-1899.  Which are definitely.  If today is  7/27/2015 and I add 70 days the return should be 11/7/2015. If subtract the `UAT START DATE` of 7/17/2015 the value should be 10/27.2015. How can I fixe my formula? Thanks.

Current formula: `=TEXT([CalcToday]-[UAT START DATE]+70,"mm-dd-yyyy")`

Comment: If I understand correctly, it looks like you're just trying to add 70 days to your UAT START DATE. I'm not sure why you'd do the calculation of TODAY + 70 - UAT START DATE. It seems like it could be simplified to UAT START DATE + 70.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get your [CalcToday] from?

### update: [How to use Today and Me in Calculated column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336)

No matter what the blogs out there say, You can **not** do Today in Calculated Column Formulas like you can in Excel because those Formulas are only recalculated when a List Item is updated.

So the **[TODAY]** Trick you read on blogs is producing almost the same output as the standard SharePoint *Modified* value... *almost* because *Modified* gives you a date and Today gives you the time as well.

There is no need for the **[TODAY]** trick on newer SharePoint versions because there is the **Today()** function...
Which is also only updated when a List Item is updated!!

If you want to do Today Calculations **in a View** you can do the math in JavaScript: [Can anyone color code a column with an if statement?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145693/can-anyone-color-code-a-column-with-an-if-statement/145702#145702)