# change SharePoint list field color using jquery code base on value?

Tags: development, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working with SharePoint list and I need to change the Number field color if it is greater than 60. I tried to change the code below but it did't work. I also checked all answers but none of them solved my problem.

This is my code which didn't work (I tried to use gt)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $Text = $("td .ms-vb2:gt('60')").filter(function() {
         return $(this).text() == "td .ms-vb2";})
         $Text.css("background-color", "#00FF66");
    }); 
</script>
```

I also used calculate column as you said but it contain error:
[image: This is my formula and what I was trying with your answers]
[image: This is error when I ok the column]

Comment: Your last mention of the column says Distancer instead of Distance

Comment: ohh! let me check I didn't  see that!

Comment: I checked it still not working and syntax error

Comment: And Distance is a number field, not single line of text?

Comment: yes, Distance is a number field

Comment: I also changed some syntax and replaced them in different way but it didn't work

Comment: try starting with pieces, for example... `=IF(Distance>60,"greater","less")` ... then add in pieces until it breaks and you'll know what's wrong with the syntax

Comment: Thank you for answer.I will let you know the result when I checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated field return as a number using the formula below, and display the calculated field in the view instead of your number field:

`=IF(Number>60," <div style='background-color:#00FF66;'>"&Number&"</div>"," <div style='background-color:#00FF66'>"&Number&"</div>")`

Comment: Thanks it is great but it didn't work and  when I replaced the Column Named Distance with Number it says syntax error.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your formula to your original post?

Comment: sure! I posted above.

Comment: I tried but it didn't work& I am closing to the idea that a feature is close or something is not activate in administration. do you have any idea for  that ?

Comment: @Shadi the separator could be different for you, it depends on the locale. In the example above ( haven't tested it), the sepertor is `,` , but like in my locale I have to use `;` instead of `,`

Comment: I marked because I were suggested by others as well. for others it worked and I should find the way. but I think this is the best way

Answer (score 1):

You can use JS link for your problem..

With JS Link, users can add a reference to their JavaScript Files as a WebPart property, and Control the Rendering of Fields & Items in Views, List Forms (Display,New,Edit) and event in WebParts.

And detailed answer of your problem is in the link below..

[Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Hope this resolves your problem..

Comment: thanks! there was a problem in this case when I uploaded the js file into the Master Page Gallery there was only 2 content type fro publishing page, where should I bring the JavaScript content type?

Comment: You can add the same from site content types.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: No! despite all answers I faced with errors. I am trying to solve and if I found the way surly I will write here! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your code is firing too early.  I often need to wrap my javascript/jquery in a function that fires using the _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames array.

Example:

```
function wrapperFunction(){
   *code to run*
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("wrapperFunction");
```

Comment: Thanks but can I ask something: is it some additional code to myself coding? Since I am fresh code writer and I was trying to mix some codes I think my code include some mistakes as well. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that using a calculated field or CSR (jslink) is a better option. But if you needs to do it the way you are doing it, then it looks like you are doing it wrong. The `:gt` selector is an index selector. From the docs:

> **index-related selectors**
>
> The index-related selector expressions (including this "greater than"
>   selector) filter the set of elements that have matched the expressions
>   that precede them. They narrow the set down based on the order of the
>   elements within this matched set. For example, if elements are first
>   selected with a class selector (.myclass) and four elements are
>   returned, these elements are given indices 0 through 3 for the
>   purposes of these selectors.

And a number field, at least on `SP 2013` is inside a `div` in the `td`, with a `.ms-number` class.

You could do something like this:

```
  $("table.ms-listviewtable > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(columnNumber) > div").filter(function() { 
        ( parseInt( $(this).text() ) > 59 ) ? $(this).css("background-color", "#00FF66") : null   
    });
```

Note the :nth-child, replace the columnNumber with column order the number field is in your listview, it's zero based, column 3 = nth-child(2).

The drawbacks are obvious, if someone changes the order, or adds more number fields if you are using `.ms-number` as selector. That is why calculated column or CSR is the way to go.

Comment: thanks but as you said the list should be so flexible in Col order and I think is would be a bit risky but thank you for output. surely I will use somewhere else.