# Calculated Column that will trigger the word "expired" in another column

Tags: date-time

I am looking to create a calculated column that will trigger the word "expired" in another column if the date is less then or equal to today's date. Do you know what formula I would use for this?

Comment: or use column validation in the same column without using a calculated column.

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported by MS to use the **current date** in a calculated field. You should look for another approach. You can try with JSlink.

I think this can help you: [Change the color of a row when Date >= today's date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177564/change-the-color-of-a-row-when-date-todays-date)