# Function always return same value instead throw else clauseif condition is not valid

Tags: javascript, date-time, jslink, moment

I have this query running from JSLink into list. It get current time from `moment.js` and compare date with sharepoint column `ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento;` and return result into column `sCumplimientoInicial`

```
 function overrideCumplimiento(ctx) {
         var sIconFileName = "";


    var currentServerDateTime = moment().format("DD/MM/YYYY"); 
    var sCumplimiento = ctx.CurrentItem.Cumplimiento;
    var sCumplimientoInicial = ctx.CurrentItem.Fecha_x0020_Compromiso_x0020_Ini;


      if(currentServerDateTime < sCumplimientoInicial){
       sCumplimiento  = 'Yes'
      }else{
       sCumplimiento  = 'No'
      }
    return sCumplimiento;
   }
```

Problem is when `currentServerTime` is bigger than `sCumplimientoInicial` it return "Yes" instead "No", and it always return Yes. Any idea what is wrong there?

I think it is because `sCumplimiento` is an string and no date. Because if I select first, second of any month it return `no` so it is not comparing from dates just from string. How can I achieve this comparation of dates correctly?

UPDATE:
As comments below I try to do it using

```
 var sCumplimientoInicial = moment("ctx.CurrentItem.Fecha_x0020_Compromiso_x0020_Ini");
```

But I getting "Invalid Date"

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cast a `string` field to `date` try this

```
var FDate = new Date(your field with DateTime Data Type);
```

Ex:  `var FDate = new Date(ctx.CurrentItem.Fecha_x0020_Compromiso_x0020_Ini);`

**Note:** in case your field is string, try to parse your code with `moment`

```
var momentDate = moment("your field");
```

In case it's not working, try to customize your string in the correct date format `"MM/dd/yyyy"` then parse the output to date as the following

```
var day  = str.substring(0,2);
var mon = str.substring(3,5);
var yr  = str.substring(6,10);  
var dateformated = mon + "/" + day + "/" + yr;
var sCumplimientoInicial = Date.parse(dateformated);
```

---

To compare with `today` try this

```
 var today = new Date();
```

So the condition should look like

```
if(today < FDate )

{
       sCumplimiento  = 'Yes'

}
else
{
       sCumplimiento  = 'No'
}
```

Comment: I try it but I get Invalid date into my field... format of my field is "dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: check the updated answer!

Comment: I try it, but same result, check my update in my question

Comment: `Date.parse` work but I don´t know why it works because their output are numbers not formated date, so I´m comparing a date formated as "dd/mm/yyyy" with parse date like 1509001200000, can you explain how it works?

Comment: Glad to hear that, I think These links would help you why it worked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242627/why-does-date-parse-not-return-a-date-object , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4321270/regarding-javascript-new-date-and-date-parse

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** have to do the calculations;

SharePoints adds a 'GetDaysAfterToday' function

see: [Change the color of a row when Date >= today's date](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177564/change-the-color-of-a-row-when-date-todays-date/177569#177569)