# Sharepoint 2013 - Change Color of Due Date if it is past today's date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I am new to sharepoint and do not have knowledge of coding.

I have few columns in sharepoint task list
"Column A" "Column B" "Date Assigned" "Due Date"

I would like the date in "Due Date" to change color automatically if it is past due.

Is it possible to do this in Classic Experience on sharepoint without too much coding?

Old sharepoint use to say automatically, "PAST DUE" and color it red before in Task List.

Answer (score 5):

[Here is a link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177564/change-the-color-of-a-row-when-date-todays-date) to a previous post that I think will do what you are asking for.  It does require a bit of custom code, but OP seems to have done a good job explaining how to set it up.  Good Luck

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new Tasks List based on the OOB Tasks List template to test.
[image]

In my testing, when Due Date is passed, the color of the value is changed to Red:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This only applies to the SharePoint App Task list:

To have passed Due date display in red the **Check mark column must be included**. Add it to the View and it displays passed due dates in red.

Also if you wish standard date formatted as `mm/dd/yyyy` (dependent on General Settings) this can be altered in the Due date Column settings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need coding at all to achieve that, it's an OOTB functionality.

To display the past Due date column in red, there is the only requitement - "Due date" column should show date only (not sate and time), change that in the column' settings.