# Change row color according to status field

Tags: client-side-rendering

I have the following code. I'm trying to change row background colors based on the status field. But it is not working.

```
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
  OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
    var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
    for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
    {
      var Completed = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus."] == "0";
      if (Completed)
      {
        var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
        var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
        tr.style.backgroundColor = "#00ff00";
      }
```

Comment: You might check this here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013

Comment: i am trying this code but this is not giving me any result

Comment: That script is definitly working. Please try creating a new list with just title and status plus the status values and add the script into an script editor

Comment: yeah but i need to run that code without using "for" or foreach

Comment: Put a ``debugger;``  statement before the Completed declaration and trace what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are putting this script in JSLink and it is not working then try putting this code in Script Editor WebPart because it worked for me.

If you are facing any other issue please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: yeah its working