# Color custom list items based on Status using OOTB

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, ootb

I want to change color of the list item row based on the field value without any code.

**For Example :** I do have custom list with fields Title, Status(Pending,Running,Completed). I want to color list items based on color like If Status is

1. Pending than row color should be yellow
2. Running than row color should be light green
3. Completed than row color should be dark green.

Can somebody please let me know the easy step to do that **without code using just SharePoint designer** or **any other out of the box solution**?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SharePoint 2013 was introduced a so called Client Rendering Mode (CSR) which represents a rendering engine for list views, list forms and search results. I would recommend you to consider the following approach for your task.

[Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:
1. Get your coloring logic in a JS file.
An example:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var colors =  {
          'Pending' : '#40f600',  
          'Running' : '#f9af00',
          'Completed' : '#f93030' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["Status"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = colors[status];
       }
     } 
   });
});
```

This script sets the color based on a value of the Status column.

2. Upload your JS file to a library within a site.
3. Go to your list view in SharePoint, start editing the page.
4. Select the list view web part and go to it's properties.
5. Expand `Miscellaneous` and specify the location of a JLink file.

Comment: it work for me but the only change i need to do is instead of putting it in list view WebPart Miscellaneous setting, i kept the script in script editor WebPart