# Color custom list items based on Date

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

In SP/O365 online, I need to add colors to list items in an announcement webpart according to the date. I have been looking at the following article: [Color custom list items based on Status using OOTB](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/177620/color-custom-list-items-based-on-status-using-ootb?noredirect=1&lq=1) which is coming close to what I need, but I lack the knowledge to change this script to my needs.

New list items should show in a different color (not the background, but item itself) and it needs to change to default after a specific amount of time, like f.e. a month after the created date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Learn to use the [Cisar Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisar/nifbdojdggkboiifaklkamfpjcmgafpo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used CSR templates to get this customization. Below is snippet. This can be reused.

`(function () {
    var requestCtx = {};
    requestCtx.Templates = {};
    requestCtx.OnPostRender = highlightFields;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(requestCtx);
})();
function highlightFields(ctx) {
    var cellIndex = -1;
    $(".ms-listviewtable thead th").each(function(index){
        if($(this).find("div [name='Created']")) {
            cellIndex = $(this).index();
        }
    });
    if(cellIndex > -1) {
        $(".ms-listviewtable tbody tr").each(function(index){
            var strDate = $(this).find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").find("span").attr("title");
            var days = Math.round((new Date() - new Date(strDate))/1000/60/60/24);
            if(days < 30) {
                $(this).closest("tr").find("td").addClass("text-success");
            }
        });
    }

}`

in the snippet "text-success" is my css class and you can replace with your own class.

`.text-success {
color: green;
}`

you will see output as follows
[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. Will try to implement this to an alerts list the coming week.

Comment: As I am working on a SP that is controlled by another big firm, I have no access to Design Manager unfortunately to add snippet. I have tried to js link to this script file within the webpart options. With no success however.

Comment: Made a page with an alerts list. Put the above script into Script Editor webpart (adding <script></script>). Put the CSS into another Script Editor (adding <style></style). Still can't get it working. Because SP language is dutch, I have changed 'created' to 'Gemaakt', but still can't get it green...

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach is:

1. to create a workflow that assign a value depending on time past since creation and then
2. using this value to select a custom CSS assigned to your lists
3. using a Calculated Column to push the CSS into the list

   More specifically:

   1. workflow 2010: `find days between Current Item:Created and Today`
   2. Create a calculated column and put this formula (of course oyu've to adapt to your columns) and **set data type returned as number** (this is the only way SP will read this as HTML):

`=IF([PastDays]>5,:"<div style='background-color:gold; color:white; '>"&[PastDays]&"</div>",[PastDays])`

In this example the cell of *PastDays* will be red with white font if this value is > than 5. Of course you can nest many condition and give more complicated style definition.

Comment: Good idea about the workflow assigning a value on passed time. However Calculated Column pushing CSS sounds unknown to me.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now. Will try this the coming days if I have access to workflows...

Comment: I've created the calculated column, but when I paste code into formula and hit ok, SP returns error msg. But the biggest problem is that in workflows, I can only chose basic 'approval' and 'three-state', 'find days between item' is not in the list.

Comment: I managed to create a calculated column (named Age) that returns a number using Formula Today-Created (and then deleting Today column). I have a value now, but when I add your formula (changing PastDays with Age), it goes wrong. Is PastDays referring to the list, the column or the workflow result?

Comment: You have to build a workflow in SharePoint Designer. Build a 2010 WF and get the number of days between the 2 dates, then set it in a column (here I called it PastDays) .