# Status Indicator using Calculated Columns

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, status, new-indicator

I am wanted to create a status indicator for a calendar. I'd prefer to use something that I can manipulate within a calculated column. I can work with multiple columns, but in the end I want it to give me the options of R A G and produce three colors on my list view. If I can get the colors in the form view, that would be even better, but is not required.

Answer (score 3):

Try referencing the following:

- [Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)
- https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/
- https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/80613cb7-10c9-4d96-8b91-a36f3feaec62/sharepoint-2013-calculated-column-formula-to-change-text-color-based-on-another-column?forum=sharepointgeneral

Answer (score 2):

@hoffie4 
•https://blog.splibrarian.com/2012/06/06/using-calculated-columns-to-add-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/

Thank you so much! I found in the comments of the article you sent me that if you select "Number" instead of "Line of single text" you can skip the steps after 4. in the solution for 2010. This worked out great for me, but I could not seem to get the indicator symbols with the online instantiation of SharePoint. Regardless this gave me a workable solution. Thanks!