# set/change timeline color based on column value

Tags: tasks, task-list, timeline

Is it possible to set/change the color of a callout or block in the timeline of a task list based on the value of a column in the relevant task? I am trying to develop a task list with a Status column. The Status values are Good, Bad, Neutral. I have added a script to color code the task item row based on the Status value ([referencing this solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)) and I want to find a way to automatically color the task callout or block in the timeline as well. That way, when someone sets the Status value the row and the timeline block or callout will be colored accordingly.

If possible, I want to also make sure that when a task is added to the timeline, the color of the task in the timeline is determined (on page load is fine) based on the existing value of the Status field. This way, it is not just the changing of the status field that sets the timeline color.

Comment: I think this could help : [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Comment: thanks for the link. I've looked at that myself and it is useful, but it's not the answer I'm looking for. I want to color the timeline, not the task list.