# Conditional formatting row font style and color

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, style-library

I have a list where the font style and color for the rows are conditionally formatted based on the value of the status column.  I don't want to highlight the row, just change the font.  Below is an example:

[image]

To achieve the font styles the below code works fine when "group by" is set to "expanded" but when I set the group by setting to "collapsed" the code not longer works. Evidently missing something but not sure what.

```
$(function(){
   $("td.ms-vb2").each(function(){
       var that = $(this);
       if (that.text() == "Not Approved"){
           that.parent("tr").children("td").css("color", "#B0E0E6");
           that.parent("tr").children("td").css("font-style", "italic");
            }
       else if (that.text() == "Pending"){
           that.parent("tr").children("td").css("color", "#FF0000");
           that.parent("tr").children("td").css("font-style", "italic");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSLink to change the style of non approved items

See the question here: [Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Comment: For a wacky non-jQuery-Calculated-Column solution, see http://www.viewmaster365.com/#/How , works because it sets the TR style on every display, where as the jQuery solution only executes on page load

Comment: Tried the viewmaster365 solution but got some strange effects when hovering over the formatted rows, also I could only get background highlight but I wanted to only format font, thus reverted to the original code I posted.
Now guessing that I could set to expanded as default then have js collapse the groupings.

Comment: Then CSR with JSLinks is the SP route to take, start by disabling MDS, that will save you some dev headaches. But don't invest too much energy in it, it is unclear if and how, Microsoft will support CSR in Modern Experiences (and at the moment you can't add ANY code to those Modern Experiences)

Comment: See https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views

Comment: [link](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/620110/sharepoint-client-side-rendering-list-views#premain879731)

Comment: The link above is the same as the one Danny provided. It scrolls to the example highlighting rows