# Coloring a Library column based on scores(digits)

Tags: calculated-column, library

First of all I would like to thank everyone involved in answering questions and providing solutions on this site. You heroes have helped me a lot in creating a site for my departement without any SP background or programming background.

But now I am having trouble meeting one requirement. Which is coloring a column in a Library in the UI of SP 2010. We keep a score and we want to visualize our overview using colors. We are looking for a method to color this scores column as the following:

- 0-25 = Green
- 26-50 = Yellow
- higher than 50 = Red

I hope i am clear enough, if not please ask more information. Thank you all once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will require some code where you will need to set the conditions so different colors appear in each row when data in your list is changed. The code will be in a JavaScript file that you will need to connect to your list's web part. I recommend making a test list to figure it out before you do this on your actual list just to figure out how it works.

See this post for more info as it helped me in the past. 
[Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

Answer (score 0):

There are third party providers like 'Sparqube' who have something that would help with this; they have an 'indicator' field type which you can configure to colour the line or field based on the item value.

Otherwise some custom coding would do this I think.  Though I don't know how to do this.

If you want a non-coding solution, you could use a calculated field with an 'IF' statement e.g. IF value is between 0-25, return "Green" (as text), a calculated column would not change the line green.