# Color Coding List Item by Web Part based on value

Tags: list, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering, formatting

I am currently trying to get color coding on a list to highlight good medium and bad properties.

I have tried to follow the examples shown here for color coding: [SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

As well as here:
[Color code item row based on column value in SharePoint Foundation 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/132857/color-code-item-row-based-on-column-value-in-sharepoint-foundation-2013)

I cannot figure out why none of the approaches are succeding for me. I have placed it as a webpart on the site and tested that i was able to modify the tables by just adding a footer text. But it must be something about reading the custom field.

The latest i used in the webpart was:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
     OnPostRender: function(ctx) {

       var statusColors =  {
          'BP Authorized' : '#FFF1AD',  
          'Other' : '#FFD800',
          'BP Selected' : '#01DF3A' 
       };

       var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
       for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
       {
          var status = rows[i]["CATEGORY"];
          var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
          var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
          row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
       }
     }
   }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Are using SharePoint Online/2016/2013 or anything else?

Comment: Where are you adding this code? You need to add this in JSLink property of List web part.

Comment: It is Sharepoint 2013.
I am adding it as web part underneath the list in the page layout.

Comment: Are you positive that `CATEGORY` (exactly that, in all caps) is the internal name of the column?  Also, what type of column is it?  I created a test list, added a choice column with that exact internal name, with those exact choice values, and added your code as-is through a content editor web part _below_ the LVWP (just as you describe), and your code works fine.  The only things I can think of are if you don't have the column internal name right, or if it is a lookup or some other type of column and the column values are not the strings you are expecting.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is `CATEOGRY` - It is as custom column with a type `choice`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are adding this code in wrong place.

Try following approach:

**How to set the JSLink property of your Web Part:**

1. Create JavaScript file with the code you are using.
2. Click on Gear icon at top right corner.
3. Edit the Page on which you have added list web part.
4. Select the list web part and edit web part properties.
5. Go to Miscellaneous --> JS Link property.
6. Add the reference to newly create file in JSLink property.

**Update**:

Also, try putting your code inside below block:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    //your code goes here
});
```

See my answer given [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/252371/how-to-color-code-a-sharepoint-list-date-field-based-on-comparison-with-todays-d/252380).

**Complete Code**:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() { 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) {
            var statusColors =  {
                'BP Authorized' : '#FFF1AD',  
                'Other' : '#FFD800',
                'BP Selected' : '#01DF3A' 
            };
            debugger;
            var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
            for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
            {
                var status = rows[i]["CATEGORY"];
                var rowId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
                var row = document.getElementById(rowId); 
                row.style.backgroundColor = statusColors[status];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Where `CATEGORY` is internal name of your choice column. You can get the correct internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Path**:

1. Save this `JSLink.js` file in same site and add path to miscellaneous--> as `~site/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`. **OR**
2. Save this `JSLink.js` file in same site collection and add path to miscellaneous--> as `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`.

Comment: I was under the impression that both doing it as a web part or as a JSLink. Will try the JSLink and get back.

Comment: Added the Code to a ".js" and put it in SiteAssets.

Made a link under misc to ~SiteAssets/Filename.js, but still without luck

Comment: @Daniel the URL tokens you can use are `~sitecollection` or `~site`, not `~SiteAssets`.  The path in your JSLink should be `~site/SiteAssets/Filename.js`.

Comment: Updated the link to match. Made no changes to appearance.

Comment: Have you added `SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {` block to make sure `clienttemplates.js` file is loaded? Are you sure field's **internal name** is `CATEGORY`?

Comment: Updated the Code piece to match the suggested from you in the `.js` file, so it matches you **Complete Code**.

Comment: And what about field's internal name? Also you are adding this jslink on the SharePoint List(same list where the category column is) App web part, right?

Comment: The internal name was wrong. I was sure i checked, and i checked again, but it must had been for a different list. Sorry for the confusion. I only got the script working for the embeded code and not as a JS link.
I have placed the exact code as you have written under **Complete Code** but with updated column name.
My `.js` file is placed here: `/com/c001421/SiteCollection`, and the link in misc for the web app part with the column is `~site/SiteCollections/Filename.js`. What am i doing wrong with the JSLink?

Comment: Go to the page where you have added this web part. Open browser's console and check if there is any error mentioning `404-Failed to load resource or File not found` type error for your js file? If Yes, Then check from where it is trying to load that file by hovering over the link at right side of the error.

Comment: There are no errors, but only some warnings as **SEC7115**, **HTML1300**, and **HTML1202** according to [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/hh180764(v=vs.85)) , but also an warning with this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/dev-guides/dn265017(v=vs.85))