# JSLink Column Format is not taking action

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, javascript, sharepoint-list, column-formatting

I have a list of type **Classic Experience** that contain column **"Status"** assume the following values: Approved, Pending, and Rejected. Each of these values contain a color format based on Javascript code. I added the file in SiteAssets library and i call my file by JSLink. After reloading the page and creating new items no action was taken. This is the code:

```
    (function () { 

    // Create object that have the context information about the field that we want to change it's output render  
    var statusFiledContext = {}; 
    statusFiledContext.Templates = {}; 
    statusFiledContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Status": { "View": StatusFiledTemplate } 
    }; 

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFiledContext); 

})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function statusFiledTemplate(ctx) { 

    var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 

    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    switch (status) { 
        case "Approved": 
            return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Pending": 
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Rejected": 
            return "<span style='color :#cab023'>" + status + "</span>"; 
    } 
}
```

and i check my console i got the following errors:

```
    GET https://static.sharepointonline.com/bld/_layouts/15/test//mysite/siteassets/prioritycolor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
4theming.js:1 Cannot find theme color: SubtleBodyText
theming.js:1 Cannot find theme color: SearchURL
theming.js:1 Cannot find theme color: SubtleBodyText
3theming.js:1 Cannot find theme color: ErrorText
2theming.js:1 Cannot find theme color: HeaderSubtleText
init.js:1 Exception while trying to access stylesheet rules: SecurityError: Failed to read the 'cssRules' property from 'CSSStyleSheet': Cannot access rules
```

Any idea what's the problem and how could i fix it ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need modify the code as below.

```
(function () {
    var statusFieldContext = {}; 
    statusFieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    statusFieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Status": { "View": statusFieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldContext); 
})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function statusFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    switch (status) { 
        case "Approved": 
            return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Pending": 
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Rejected": 
            return "<span style='color :#cab023'>" + status + "</span>"; 
    } 
}
```

and use the url as below in JSLINK.

**`~site/SiteAssets/prioritycolor.js`**

Or we can add the code below into script editor web part in list view page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {
    var statusFieldContext = {}; 
    statusFieldContext.Templates = {}; 
    statusFieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
        // Apply the new rendering for Priority field on List View 
        "Status": { "View": statusFieldTemplate } 
    }; 
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(statusFieldContext); 
})(); 

// This function provides the rendering logic for list view 
function statusFieldTemplate(ctx) {
    var status = ctx.CurrentItem[ctx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name]; 
    // Return html element with appropriate color based on priority value 
    switch (status) { 
        case "Approved": 
            return "<span style='color :#f00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Pending": 
            return "<span style='color :#ff6a00'>" + status + "</span>"; 
            break; 
        case "Rejected": 
            return "<span style='color :#cab023'>" + status + "</span>"; 
    } 
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you ! It works fine now !

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the errors, I think this issue is because your JSLink file is not loaded properly.

There is some specific syntax to give the path of `.js` file in JSLink, check below:

**Path**:

1. Save this `JSLink.js` file in **same site** and add path to miscellaneous --> as `~site/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`. **OR**
2. Save this `JSLink.js` file in **same site collection** and add path to miscellaneous --> as `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`.

For more details, check my answer given at [Color Coding List Item by Web Part based on value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266194/color-coding-list-item-by-web-part-based-on-value/266195#266195).

Comment: Thanks for help!

Comment: Great. If this answer helped you in any way then please upvote(^) and [accept is it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).