# sharepoint 2013 list expand/collapse multiple line text column

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jslink, client-side-rendering, multiple-lines-of-text

I'm desperate and need your help on this script. I have a "multi line text" column named "Comments", and i added the following script into a script editor but it is not working for me. could you please help fix this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function () {

 var linkFieldContext = {};
 linkFieldContext.Templates = {};
 linkFieldContext.Templates.Fields = { 
 "Comments": { "View": CommentRendering}

};
 SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(linkFieldContext);
})();

function ExpandDescription(a){

var small=a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('Small');
 small[0].style.display='none'; 
var full=a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('Full');
 full[0].style.display='block';

}

function CollapseDescription(a){

var small=a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('Small');
 small[0].style.display='block'; 
var full=a.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('Full');
 full[0].style.display='none';

}

function CommentRendering(ctx)
{
 var htmlStr = "";
 var itemId = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;
 var itemDesc = ctx.CurrentItem.Comments;
var div = document.createElement("div");

div.innerHTML =itemDesc;

itemDesc = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
if(itemDesc.length>50){
 var itemDescSmall=itemDesc.substring(0, 50);
 htmlStr='+itemDescSmall+…Expand
'}else{return ctx.CurrentItem.Comments;} return htmlStr;}
</script>
```

Comment: where did you add tag with "Small" and "Full" class name?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this script in script editor will not work.

You need to add it in JSLink property of List web part.

Try below steps:

**How to set the JSLink property of your Web Part:**

1. Create JavaScript file with the code you are using.
2. Click on Gear icon at top right corner.
3. Edit the Page on which you have added list web part.
4. Select the list web part and edit web part properties.
5. Go to Miscellaneous --> JS Link property.
6. Add the reference to newly create file in JSLink property.

**Path**:

1. Save this `JSLink.js` file in same site and add path to miscellaneous--> as `~site/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`. **OR**
2. Save this `JSLink.js` file in same site collection and add path to miscellaneous--> as `~sitecollection/SiteAssets/JSLink.js`.

For more details, check my answer given  at [Color Coding List Item by Web Part based on value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266194/color-coding-list-item-by-web-part-based-on-value/266195#266195)

Comment: Hi Ganesh, thanks a lot for your help. the list view webpart is already linked to one JS Link file, as such i cannot link this one

Comment: Ok, But you can merge both codes in order to make it work.

Comment: Have you managed to get it working? Or you are facing any issue?