# Add to Hyperlink to column in SharePoint List using JSLINK - Help

Tags: jslink

I'm having issues adding a hyperlink to a field using the below.
My column field is called LinkTitle (single Line of Text)
My view is called Dashboard and i have refrenced the js like so 
~sitecollection/SiteName/SiteAssets/jsLink.js
But it doesn't work.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong or missing?

```
(function () {  

    // Create an object that have the context information about the fields that we want to change the rendering of.   

    var nameFiledContext = {};  

    nameFiledContext.Templates = {};  

    nameFiledContext.Templates.Fields = {  

        // Apply the new hyperlink HTML Rendering to the field in your view.  Swap out "<Your Field Name>" for your field name 

        "LinkTitle": { "View": DashBoard }  

    };  

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(nameFiledContext);  

})();  



// This function applies the rendering logic 

function DashBoard(ctx) {  

    var name = ctx.CurrentItem.LinkTitle;  //Swap out name variable for whatever field contains your hyperlink name



    return "<a target='_blank' href='http://google.com"   

        + name + "</a>";      //Put the url for your hyperlink in the href above

}
```

Comment: Try your code in the way I mentioned in my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/275592/open-sharepoint-list-items-in-edit-mode/275597#275597. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh,
The sample you proposed only works for Title field i added Edit (link to edit item) But the links only appeared on the Title field. Also changed to a different column but no luck

Comment: All good , It just took a while to replicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use the [Client Side Rendering](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views) like below:

```
(function () {
    function registerRenderer() {
        var ctxForm = {};
        ctxForm.Templates = {};

        ctxForm.Templates = {
            Fields : {
                'LinkTitle': { //------ Change Hyperlink of LinkTitle
                    View : function (ctx) {
                        var url = String.format('{0}?ID={1}', "/sites/SiteName/Lists/ListName/EditForm.aspx", ctx.CurrentItem.ID);
                        return String.format('<a href="{0}" onclick="EditItem2(event, \'{0}\');return false;">{1}</a>', url, ctx.CurrentItem.Title);
                    }
                },
            }
        };
        SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(ctxForm);
    }
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
})();
```

Here I have added the edit form link on `Title (linked to item with edit menu)` column whose internal name is `LinkTitle`. If you want to add it on another column then you need to add the internal name of your column instead of `LinkTitle`.

You can get the internal name of your column by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**How to set the JSLink property of your Web Part:**

For detailed steps, check my answer given at: [sharepoint 2013 list expand/collapse multiple line text column](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269087/sharepoint-2013-list-expand-collapse-multiple-line-text-column/269089#269089)

Answer (score 0):

Use the  masterpage gallery or styles library location to store the jslink file and reference as below:

Sitecollection level: `~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/<your js file>.js`

Site level: `~site/_catalogs/masterpage/<your js file>.js`