# Creating a hyperlink from a variable value (from another column) - SP2019

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, 2019, classic-experience

Is it possible to create a hyperlink in SharePoint 2019 (classic list) so that it contains data from a different column?

I have an ID column that contains information that I would like to automatically include in the hyperlink in the URL column.

| ID | URL |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | https://mysite.sharepoint.com/1234 |
| 5678 | https://mysite.sharepoint.com/5678 |

Ideally, the hyperlink should be visible under a different name, e.g. LINK.

Comment: **ID** is SharePoint default ID column or the custom column you created in the list?

Comment: For SP 2019 classic experience, you can use JSLink. Check this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269361/change-column-background-color-and-text-color/269373#269373. Let me know if it works for you.