# Rename 'Like' link in custom lists

Tags: 2013, custom-list, jslink, client-side-rendering, content-rating

Is there a way to rename the Like/Unlike links in a custom list where rating has been enabled?

'Like' in our case would be misleading so we would like to have it show up as something like 'Confirm'.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[Client Side Rendering (CSR)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)** for such requirements in SharePoint 2013.

Below is the code sample which replaces `Like` button by a image stored in Style Library:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({
      OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
          SP.UI.Reputation.LikesHelpers.ImageUrls.$W = "/Style Library/hand-like-32.png";
          SP.UI.Reputation.LikesHelpers.ImageUrls.$X = "/Style Library/hand-like-32.png";
      }
    });
});
```

You can find a full code and explanation at: [Custom “Like”-Button in SharePoint List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41185470/custom-like-button-in-sharepoint-list)
.

Check my answer given here to know how to set the `JSLink` property of your Web Part:
[Color Coding List Item by Web Part based on value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266194/color-coding-list-item-by-web-part-based-on-value/266195#266195)

Comment: Was hoping for a 'simple' solution but this will do :) Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. Glad it worked for you.